# Products formed on the electrolysis of wet HF

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

We know that, [electroysis of water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/12315/electrolysis-of-water) produces $\ce{O2}$ at anode and $\ce{H2}$ at cathode. In a similar way I thought that on electroysis of $\ce{HF}$ it would produce $\ce{F2}$ and $\ce{H2}$ at their respective electrodes. If this is true then [fluorine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorine) could be prepared by electroysis of $\ce{HF}$. So to verify this I was searching on internet. Then I found an article on [synthesis of $\ce{OF2}$](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ba-1966-0054.ch018#). 
 It was interesting that on electroysis of wet $\ce{HF}$ it produces a mixture of $\ce{OF2,O2,O3}$ at the anode rather than simply producing $\ce{O2}$. Then I searched on internet for the mechanism but I couldn't find it. 
 So I need an appropriate mechanism for the electroysis of $\ce{HF}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not included into consideration respective electrode redox potentials nor the fact fluorine reacts with water.

Comment: Sorry . Now I have edited question again.